# WF-1000XM3 refusing connection (Hera 5.1)

Tags: bluetooth, audio

I have been using elementary OS for a while and it's working really well until this started. While it was working the Bluetooth dialog would show 2 devices which were both named LE_WF1000XM3 and connecting to both of them would connect the earbuds. However for some reason this recently stopped working. When I attempt to do the same thing it rapidly connects and disconnects 2 times before finally stays disconnected.I have tried restarting the computer, restarting the Bluetooth service with systemctl, and connecting through the bluetoothctl command. I also tried connecting with the device in pairing mode. None of these steps change the behavior of the device. I can provide additional information on request.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by removing the headset from bluetoothctl and re pairing it